# MediaPlayer can't play audio in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Today, I make application to play music in Android.

I have failed when using `MediaPlayer` to play an audio file; it can't play any file audio.
This exception throws to log cat like:

> E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>
> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>
> W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

This code show more information; exception occurs at line:

`mediaPlayer.prepare();`

This class contains this line:

```
public void playAudio() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    fileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.file);
    playBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    String chooseFiles = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
    
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(chooseFiles);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fileName.setText(fName.substring(chooseFiles.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    mediaPlayer.start();
    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

I added permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How to fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: How does the String `chooseFiles` looks like?

Comment: `chooseFiles: "/storage/sdcard0/audio/2016-03-24 15.02.58.mp4` is path file to play audio. @RaduIonescu

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer` can not access your file, either because it can not find it, in which case you should try to append `"file://"` to your path

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/audio/2016-03-24 15.02.58.mp4
```

Or if it is a permission problem (most likely since you have this error `(1, -2147483648)`)  pass a file descriptor like this

```
File file = new File(chooseFiles);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
inputStream.close();
```